# Connect to Websocket Via Guile

Tags: tcp, websocket, scheme, guile

I have near no knowledge/experience with sockets of any kind so my question may just end up being due to my ignorance.

Guile doesn't have any concept of the protocol but I figure, since websockets are just HTTP requests, I should be able to at least make a request out using Guile's web modules.

I'm using wss://node2.wsninja.io from https://wsninja.io/#demo to practice on.

I wrote up

```
(let ([s                                                  (socket PF_INET SOCK_STREAM 0)]
      [d (vector-ref (addrinfo:addr (car (getaddrinfo "echo.websocket.org" "https"))) 1)])
  (connect s AF_INET d 443))
```

to attempt connecting. While `getaddrinfo` asks for a protocol (and Guile doesn't recognize `"wss"` or `"ws"`), I only really need the IP address as an integer and that's all it's really doing – extracting the integer representation; the result matches what I got verifying against a few other services on the web so it seems right.

I used `PF_INET` and `AF_INET` since, if I'm not mistaken, IPv4 makes sense for a websocket call. I went with `SOCK_STREAM` since a websocket'll be streaming data back and forth, once opened.

I based the above example off of the client example given by Guile here: https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Internet-Socket-Examples.html#Internet-Socket-Examples.

I suspect it's the next portion that I've got wrong somehow but I'm not sure how.

I assumed, after connecting, the next step was to initiate the handshake. Given the Guile example, it seemed this could be accomplished by displaying to the now (in theory) opened port so I did this:

```
(let ([s                                                  (socket PF_INET SOCK_STREAM 0)]
      [d (vector-ref (addrinfo:addr (car (getaddrinfo "echo.websocket.org" "https"))) 1)])
  (connect s AF_INET d 443)
  (display "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"          s)
  (display "Host: localhost\r\n"         s)
  (display "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\n" s)
  (display "Upgrade: websocket\r\n"      s)
  (display "\r\n"                        s)

  (do ([line (read-line s) (read-line s)])
      ((eof-object? line))
    (display line)
    (newline)))
```

I also tried this with the handshake sent as one String, as well. The `do` loop is pretty much lifted directly from the Guile example.

While I've seen mention that the handshake should be sent as a header for Websockets, I figured it wouldn't be terribly different from HTTP and the Guile example has it sent via `display` but maybe that's a source of my error.

Needless to say, this doesn't work. Nothing gets `display`ed and the loop is exited, immediately. But it does seem like I'm making a connection because removing the `display`s to the socket results in it just hanging (what I assume is an unending loop because no `eof-object` gets sent because the socket is waiting on the handshake).

But no affirmation or even error is sent if I do send something, which I would have expected. So I'm confounded and a little out of my depth and thought I'd ask.